# Problema retornando texto

Tags: javascript, html5

o console retorna a variavel como undefined

```
carta = new Image();
    carta.src = "images/CartaVirada.png";
    carta.src2 = defineCarta(1);
    carta.position = {x:5, y:10};
    carta.numImg = criarAleatorioUnico();

function defineCarta(numCarta)
{
    if(numCarta == 1)
    {
        if (carta.numImg == 1 | carta.numImg == 2 ) return "images/Carta1.png";
        else
        {
            if (carta.numImg == 3 | carta.numImg == 4 ) return "images/Carta2.png";
                else
                {
                    if (carta.numImg == 5 | carta.numImg == 6 ) return "images/Carta3.png";
                        else
                        {
                            if (carta.numImg == 7 | carta.numImg == 8 ) return "images/Carta4.png";
                        }
                }    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás a correr `defineCarta(1);` antes de `carta.numImg = criarAleatorioUnico();`, isso faz com que dentro dessa função o valor `carta.numImg` não exista ainda.

Muda a ordem dessas linhas e já vai correr como esperas:

o console retorna a variavel como undefined

```
const carta = new Image();
carta.src = "images/CartaVirada.png";
carta.numImg = criarAleatorioUnico();
carta.src2 = defineCarta(1);
carta.position = {x:5, y:10};
```

Comment: Foi isso mesmo, muito obrigado.